# How to calculate change of data (values between 0 and 1) for different periods

Tags: data-visualization

I've replicated this model that gives numerical values between 0 and 1 as a signal for different currencies. In a sense, this evaluates the so-called 'strength' of that currency. I have 3 different periods of this strength signal: weekly, monthly and daily. Right now I'm trying to evaluate the different ways this 'strength' has fluctuated over a period of 4 weeks, 5 weeks and 3 months.

Right now I'm having trouble because of the fact that the data I have lies between 0 and 1, which makes taking changes quite difficult because you can't divide by 0. Right now I'm simply taking the difference to calculate the change within a certain period, but I was wondering if there was any better way to do this.

Comment: Just plotting the values over time will show a lot about how it's changing. It would help clarify the question if you could use that as a baseline and describe what you're looking for beyond that.

Comment: Sorry if my question seemed vague. Essentially I want to be able to make out and or be alerted to any large changes in my strength signal. I also want to be able to somehow numerically quantify the change in the signal over a 4 week, 5 week and 3 month period.